# How to fix mockery mock object throwing BadMethodCallException?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

In a silex application I have a `KafkaAPiClient` class which definitely has the public method `postMessages`.

```
<?php

namespace Kopernikus\KafkaWriter;

use Kopernikus\KafkaWriter\Model\AbstractMessage;

/**
 * KafkaApiClient.
 **/
class KafkaApiClient
{

    /**
     * @param AbstractMessage[] $msg
     */
    public function postMessages(array $messages)
    {
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            $this->postMessage($message);
        }
    }

    public function postMessage(AbstractMessage $msg)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

I can call `KafkaAPiClient::postMessages` just fine, yet when mocking the class in a test:

```
<?php
namespace unit\Request;

use Kopernikus\KafkaWriter\KafkaApiClient;

/**
 * MockeryMethodsNotBeingCallableTest
 **/
class MockeryMethodsNotBeingCallableTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMockMethodIsCallable()
    {
        $leMock = \Mockery::mock(KafkaApiClient::class);
        $leMock->postMessages([]);
    }
}
```

I am getting:

```
1) unit\Request\MockeryMethodsNotBeingCallableTest::testMockMethodIsCallable
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_11_Kopernikus_KafkaWriter_KafkaApiClient::postMessages() does not exist on this mock object

~/le-project/tests/unit/Request/MockeryMethodsNotBeingCallableTest.php:14
```

I am confused, I was expecting for the mock to not do anything yet allow the methods to be called so that I later could add my expectations on it.

Though I have found a solution, I am still wondering if it is possible to mock all the methods by default, and later check if certain ones have been called.

Comment: it says it doesn't has a postMessages() function ? i think you should check the KafkaApiClient

Comment: @MuratCemYALIN Nope, the concrete class has the method. I made absolutely sure of it, it's the mock that doesn't.

Comment: maybe it is protected or private?

Comment: @MuratCemYALIN It is public and it is not the problem. The concrete class is NOT the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists `shouldIgnoreMissing` method on the mock object. Calling that does [exactly what it says on the tin](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin), that is: ignoring calls to not yet defined methods, resulting in a mock that does nothing:

```
$leMock = \Mockery::mock(KafkaApiClient::class);
$leMock->shouldIgnoreMissing()
$leMock->postMessages([]);
```

And by nothing, it means nothing. I got into an other error for my queue when I instantiated the mock that way, as methods will return `null` by default and their return value has to be explicitly stated.

```
$msg = new Message('dummy-message');
$this->kafkaQueue
     ->shouldIgnoreMissing()
     ->shouldReceive('getMessages')->andReturn([$msg]);
```

Any call to `getMessages` will now return exactly the array `[$msg]`.

Alternatively, one can be very explicit about what methods are called with Mockery, by adding `shouldReceive`:

```
public function testMockMethodIsCallable()
{
    $leMock = \Mockery::mock(KafkaApiClient::class);
    $leMock->shouldReceive('postMessages');
    $leMock->postMessages([]);
}
```